# Ubuntu server mail server

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I wanted to ask if you could help me to start my own email server. I followed a tutorial to start my own mail server on my bought domain but something is not working.. I have a server on digital ocean and the ports 993, 995 and 465 are open. I followed this tutorial but something is not working.. I think it is the version of the linux server but i am not sure.. Can you see what am i missing and if there is some other thing to be done? Thank you

Link for the tutorial i followed: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/

Comment: Have you seen this project?
https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver I was able to set up a mail server very easily with it. if you want to keep following this tutorial, we'll need to have more logs or what is not working in order to help!

Comment: You have only given a link to the guide you followed. You have given no information about any results you got including error messages. There is no way for anyone to "see what (you) are missing" unless you give more information. "Something is not working" could literally be anything.

Comment: Other then saying over and over something is not working you also say its the version of Ubuntu. What version of Ubuntu you never gave that important bit of info. A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok sorry for my poor explanation.. i have been examining the problem and now i found logs but there are too many..
These are some of them..
 Sep 26 19:16:23 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-lon1-01 postfix/submission/smtpd[42227]: warning: hostname godwin.788555.iuz does not resolve to address 143.198.102.138: Name or service not known
Sep 26 19:16:23 ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-lon1-01 postfix/submission/smtpd[42227]: connect from unknown[143.198.102.138]
The ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS, i am using digital ocean as my hosting

Can you tell me if the docker works on digital ocean server so i can try with that?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site is best suited for specific problems, and not general questions like: "How do I set up a web server, how do I install a mail server etc." These discussions are better suited for the [Ubuntu Forum](https://www.ubuntuforums.com).